# Find Table Items By Using JS

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

i have a table like this

## TABLE

```
<table id="adminTable" style="display: inline-block">
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var person in @Model)
        {       
            <tr>
                <td style="padding: 10px;">
                    <div id="userName" style="display: inline-block">
                        <h4 name="person" id="goProfile" class="elements" style="cursor: pointer; display: inline-block">@person.DisplayName</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="userButton" style="display: inline-block;float: right" >
                        <a id="update" href="#" class="btn btn-info" style="margin-left: 6px;">Update User</a>
                        <a id="delete" href="#" class="btn btn-warning" style="margin-left: 6px;">Delete User</a>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>   

   
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

It looks like this;

[image: Table]

I need to do update or delete operations for these persons. I need to know when i pressed updateUser|DeleteUser button, i have to reach USERNAME for doing edit or delete.

My JS is here but its wrong :(

## JS

```
 $('#adminTable')
          .find('tr')
          .click(function () {
              debugger;
              var userName = $(this).find('td').text();
              var operation = parseInt($('tr').index()) + 1;
              $.ajax({
                  url: "/Admin/deleteUser",
                  type: 'POST',
                  data: { "DisplayName": userName, "op": operation },
                  success: function (data) {
                      window.location.href = 'Profile/ProfileScreen/?name=' + data.displayName;
                  }
              });
          });
```

In this code, i have an operation variable. If i can find out what im doing i can make connections with ajax but i cant reach.

Thanks alot. Now i can sleep...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you start, Make sure you are not assigning duplicate Id values to more than one element. Your current code is setting the same id values to elements inside a loop. That is invalid html!

You can keep the information you want to pass in html 5 data attributes on those buttons.

```
<a href="#" class="user-action btn btn-info"  
        data-url="@Url.Action("deleteUser","admin")" 
        data-username="@person.DisplayName" 
        data-op="update" >Update User</a>

<a href="#" class="user-action btn btn-warning" 
        data-url="@Url.Action("deleteUser","admin")" 
        data-username="@person.DisplayName" 
        data-op="delete">Delete User</a>
```

Now all you have to do is to read this data attribute values and use as needed.

```
$(function(){

   $(".user-action").click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       var d= { DisplayName : $(this).data("username"),
                Operation : $(this).data("op")
              };
       var yourUrl= $(this).data("url");
       // now make the ajax call

      $.ajax({
              url: yourUrl,
              type: 'POST',
              data: d,
              success: function (data) {

               // do something with the response data.
              }
          });  
   });

});
```

Comment: Thanks alot. I kinda recognized that somethings are wrong, thanks for informing me. I will apply your answer when i wake up. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

You can bind the click event on the button and using it can find the user name and action in the parent tags.

```js
 $('#adminTable').on("click","a",function () {
             
              var  userName = $(this).parent().parent().find(".elements").text();
              var operation = $(this).text();
            console.log("oper",operation);
              console.log("userName",userName);
             
          });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="adminTable" style="display: inline-block">
        <tbody>
     
                <tr>
                    <td style="padding: 10px;">
                        <div id="userName" style="display: inline-block">
                            <h4 name="person" id="goProfile" class="elements" style="cursor: pointer; display: inline-block">Dave</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div id="userButton" style="display: inline-block;float: right" >
                            <a id="update" href="#" class="btn btn-info" style="margin-left: 6px;">Update User</a>
                            <a id="delete" href="#" class="btn btn-warning" style="margin-left: 6px;">Delete User</a>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>          
        </tbody>
  </table>
```